# What does it mean to return a value c++?

Tags: visual-c++

In simple explanation and not technical what does it mean to return a value and void doesn't return a value? When to use void function?
I'm a beginner in c++ and function is really confusing.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void JesusChrist(int x)
{
    cout << "Favorite number is " << x << endl;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        JesusChrist(1 + (rand() % 25));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I could find a beginner C or C++ (or whatever else apart from BrainF**k really) where this wouldn't be explained...

Answer (score 1):

Returning a value is used in functions to return or give back a value which is computed in the function . In the above example ,  function JesusChrist does not return a function as the message is printed in the function itself . void functions are used when there is no need for a function to return or give back a value . 
consider a function below:

```
int increment(int x)
{
       x++;
       return(x);
}
```

now if we write a statement like below

```
x=7;
y=increment(x);
```

then y will be assigned the returned value of x ,i.e 8 in this case .

Hope you got your question clarified .

Answer (score 0):

When you `return`, two things happen:

- execution of the current function ends (you return from the function to from where it was called)
- if you return a value, the function call is evaluated as the return value of the function (you can visualize the `functionName(arguments)` call being replaced by the return value)

Note that you *can* use `return` inside `void` subroutines, but only to terminate the subroutine, not to return a value.

Wikipedia has a slightly more technical explanation: [Return statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement)